# Is there a way to change dateFormat with java 8 stream?

Tags: list, date, java-8, java-stream, date-formatting

I want to change date format from "`dd/mm/yyyy`" to "`yyyy/mm/dd`" with one line in java8 stream

```
List<String[]> date = new ArrayList<>();

String[] a= {"12/2/2018","a1","a2"};
String[] b= {"13/3/2018","b1","b2"};
String[] c= {"14/4/2018","c1","c2"};

date.add(a)`
date.add(b);
date.add(c);
```

I expect the output is

```
{{"2018/2/12","a1","a2"},{"2018/2/13","b1","b2"},{"2018/2/14","c1","c2"}}
```

Comment: how would you change the date format without Stream API?

Comment: I mean with api stream java8

Comment: @ThaeNu that's clear, but Andrew was trying to nudge you in the right direction. To be a bit more explicit, convert the list to a stream, use `map` with a function that modifies a date, collect back to list. The point of Andrew's comment was about that middle step.

Comment: date.stream().forEach(x->Arrays.stream(x).map(i -> {
   return changeDateFormat(i, "dd/mm/yyyy", "yyyy/mm/dd");
  }).forEach(System.out::print)); but I have some issue in code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you mean `yyyy/MM/dd` coz m is for minutes and M for month...

consider a Map from the stream API

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> date = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] a= {"12/2/2018","a1","a2"};
    String[] b= {"13/3/2018","b1","b2"};
    String[] c= {"14/4/2018","c1","c2"};

    date.add(a);
    date.add(b);
    date.add(c);


    List<String[]> even = date.stream().map(
            s -> {
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy");
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(s[0], formatter);
                DateTimeFormatter formatterNew = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
                return new String[]{formatterNew.format(localDate), s[1],s[2]};
            }
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    even.forEach(x-> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)));
}
```

that will print out

> [2018/02/12, a1, a2]
>
> [2018/03/13, b1, b2]
>
> [2018/04/14, c1, c2]

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this without iterating over all items.

For your simple case `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy/mm/dd` you can just use this:

```
date.forEach(i -> {
    String[] parts = i[0].split("/");
    i[0] = parts[2] + "/" + parts[1] + "/" + parts[0];
});
```

Using java time api you can use this:

```
DateTimeFormatter toFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/M/d");
DateTimeFormatter fromFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy");
date.forEach(i -> i[0] = LocalDate.parse(i[0], fromFormat).format(toFormat));
```

Comment: I’d use the java.time solution. It’s more typing, but it also makes more sense and is not so low-level.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using java 8 streams, but not in one line. Use two date patterns one for input and other for output

```
DateTimeFormatter inFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/M/yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter outFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/M/dd");

    List<String[]> date = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] a= {"12/2/2018","a1","a2"};
    String[] b= {"13/3/2018","b1","b2"};
    String[] c= {"14/4/2018","c1","c2"};

    date.add(a);
    date.add(b);
    date.add(c);

    //Since it is String array need lambda expression to update and return      

    List<String[]> result = date.stream().map(arr->{
        arr[0]=LocalDate.parse(arr[0],inFormat).format(outFormat);
        return arr;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a stream?

```
    DateTimeFormatter originalFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u");
    DateTimeFormatter wantedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u/M/d");
    date.forEach(arr -> {
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(arr[0], originalFormatter);
        arr[0] = ld.format(wantedFormatter);
    });
```

To inspect the result:

```
    date.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Output:

> ```
> [2018/2/12, a1, a2]
> [2018/3/13, b1, b2]
> [2018/4/14, c1, c2]
> ```

My code (as well as the code in some of the other answers) modifies your original arrays. Please decide if this is OK. If it is, you shouldn’t really use a stream since they are supposed to be free from side-effects. If you do need the original arrays to remain untouched, a stream is fine (using the same formatters as before):

```
    List<String[]> newDateList = date.stream()
            .map(arr -> {
                LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(arr[0], originalFormatter);
                String[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
                newArr[0] = ld.format(wantedFormatter);
                return newArr;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    newDateList.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Output is the same as before.